# Bitmap out of memory error in android...

Tags: android, memory-management, memory-leaks, android-imageview

I am working in an android application and I am using a bitmap to bind an image to an ImageView. My requirement is to rotate that ImageView and give a border to that ImageView. I have successfully implemented this, but after the application uses this activity two-three times a "force close" error appears saying Bitmap out of VM memory. Please help me to minimize the bitmap memory consumption in my code. And let me know how to modify the code for the same?

```
final int BORDER_WIDTH = 5;
        // Set the border color
        final int BORDER_COLOR = Color.WHITE;
        Bitmap res = Bitmap.createBitmap(CAPTURE_IMAGE.getWidth() + 2
                * BORDER_WIDTH, CAPTURE_IMAGE.getHeight() + 2 * BORDER_WIDTH,
                CAPTURE_IMAGE.getConfig());
        System.gc();
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(res);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(BORDER_COLOR);
        canvas.drawRect(0, 0, res.getWidth(), res.getHeight(), paint);

        canvas.drawBitmap(CAPTURE_IMAGE, BORDER_WIDTH, BORDER_WIDTH, paint);
        Matrix mat = new Matrix();
        // Set the Imageview position
        mat.postRotate(355);

        bMapRotate = Bitmap.createBitmap(res, 0, 0, res.getWidth(),
                res.getHeight(), mat, true);
        System.gc();
        res.recycle();
        res = null;
        paint = null;
        canvas = null;
        mat = null;
        // Set the captured bitmap image in the imageview
        mShareImageView.setImageBitmap(bMapRotate);
```

Comment: i've created a nice JNI solution that avoids out-of-memory by removing the max heap size limitation barrier . [**here's a link**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14398670/android-rotating-a-bitmap-using-jni-ndk#comment20033361_14398670) to my snippet. some notes: - replace in the code every instance of "uint16_t" with "uint32_t" (that's the bug on my code i've asked about) . - input and output bitmap must be with 8888 config (which is ARGB ) - input bitmap will be recycled during the process . - the code rotates the image 90 degress counter clock wise . of course you can change it depending

Answer (score 3):

I think you should use shrink function like this

```
bMapRotate = Bitmap.createBitmap(res, 0, 0, res.getWidth(),
                res.getHeight(), mat, true);


Bitmap myBitmap = ShrinkBitmap(bMapRotate , 300, 300);

mShareImageView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap );


private Bitmap ShrinkBitmap(String file, int width, int height) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        BitmapFactory.Options bmpFactoryOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bmpFactoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file, bmpFactoryOptions);

        int heightRatio = (int)Math.ceil(bmpFactoryOptions.outHeight/(float)height);
        int widthRatio = (int)Math.ceil(bmpFactoryOptions.outWidth/(float)width);

        if (heightRatio > 1 || widthRatio > 1)
        {
         if (heightRatio > widthRatio)
         {
          bmpFactoryOptions.inSampleSize = heightRatio;
         } else {
          bmpFactoryOptions.inSampleSize = widthRatio;
         }
        }

        bmpFactoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file, bmpFactoryOptions);
     return bitmap;
    }
```

it worked for me and i avoided  Bitmap out of VM memory exception

Comment: Hi.Thanks for the reply.But in the method ShrinkBitmap it passes a parameter File which I don't have .

Comment: but you must be picking file from some where can't you use that

Comment: bMapRotate is not file path. It is a Bitmap object.Please check your code.

Comment: ya but i want give you an idea , can't you get the path of your image

Comment: No..Its stored in Bitmap.It does not have a local file path.Thats why I asked you.

Answer (score 3):

in mainfest file add ---> android:largeHeap:"true"

Comment: Just a note for others: I tried putting this in my `<activity>` tags in the manifest, the one causing the errors, and it didn't work. But when I put it in the `<application>` tags it worked. Also, should be `android:largeHeap="true"`. Only use one colon.

Answer (score 1):

Try moving the `gc()` call to the end. It should run after you set `res = null` so that it can release the unused memory:

```
    res.recycle();
    res = null;
    paint = null;
    canvas = null;
    mat = null;
    System.gc();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add android:largeHeap="true" in your manifest file

Ref: largeHeap=true manifest tag not working?